# read only permission in admin interface

Tags: python, django, permissions, admin

I saw this post, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1348076/revisions , only at step 3 i'm getting confused, he tells to put  3. Add "get_view_permission" to default model class

but what's the default model class? It doesn't seem to work to me, i get following error message:

AttributeError at /admin/

'Options' object has no attribute 'get_view_permission'

Request Method:  GET
Request URL: 
Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:

'Options' object has no attribute 'get_view_permission'

So he complains about no get_view_permission, but where to place this get_view_permission???

Regards,

T

Comment: if your question regards an answer to an existing question, comment on the appropriate place. this way its more likely that you will get some help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like he means in `django/db/models.py`.

Comment: I've found it thanks, but now i have to problem, after following the tutorial... i can't click and view the data by giving another user the permission 'Can view test'... it only shows test, but you can't view it.